# How to disable Azure AD user reading UPN from a CSV file

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, power-automate

I have around 100 UPN ( User Principle Name) in a excel file.[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/services-hub/health/remediation-steps-ad/regularly-check-for-and-remove-inactive-user-accounts-in-active-directory) check user link says about the best practice. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/652531/remove-users-from-ad-group.html) link says how to remove. However, I need to disable 1st. and does not have exact info. Is there any ways to bulk disable ( NOT DELETE) all 100 accounts from Azure AD? from Azure portal or power automate or  by using PowerShell Script?

**Edit**

This code: seems for AD not for AAD.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Csv "C:\ScriptsUsers.csv" | ForEach-Object {
 $samAccountName = $_."samAccountName" 
 Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName | Disable-ADAccount
 }
```

Is there similar script available for Azure AD?

**Modification for Azure AD**

```
Import-Csv "D:\PowerShell\ScriptsUsers.csv" |
ForEach-Object {

Set-AzureADUser -ObjectID Userprincipalname -AccountEnabled $false
 }
```

However, the error shows:

> Resource 'Userprincipalname' does not exists or one of its required
> reference properties object are not present

What Am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You can do so with `Set-AzureADUser`

Comment: I need to do bulk disable not changing user properties, This 'Set-AzureADUser' looks to be changing user properties but not disable the users

Comment: Are you sure you read the documentation of the cmdlet ? One of the parameters is to set the AccountEnabled property to `$false`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using AccountEnabled property to $false. However, it show error. Very new to PowerShell. Any input?

Comment: You can do `Find-Command Set-AzureADUser` to find which module contains the needed  command and then install the chosen module using `Install-Module -Name <ModuleName>` or in this case `Install-Module -Name AzureAD`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your csv file you need to change *Userprincipalname* to $($_.CSVattribute)

```
Import-Csv "D:\PowerShell\ScriptsUsers.csv" | ForEach-Object {
  Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $($_.ObjectId) -AccountEnabled $false
}
```

or

```
Import-Csv "D:\PowerShell\ScriptsUsers.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $($_.Userprincipalname) -AccountEnabled $false
}
```